# Element involuntarily toggles upon keyboard typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, toggle

I'm in the midst of creating my first 'real' website and try to add some responsiveness to my layout and navigation: [www.dknytkom.dk/forside/](http://www.dknytkom.dk/forside/)

I use alot of addClass and removeClass to menu items as well as toggling corresponding to the width of the browser window. So far so good.

Problem is that my search field disappears upon focus when view on my iPhone. I have a vague suspicion it is to do when my jquery commands that make it go away when the document width is changed. But really I'm at a loss.

Also the toggling of the menu items tends to go awire when clicking on the menu elements even though I conditioned them to wait for the document to load. Any suggestions?

[I've tried to create a jsfiddle from where the full code can be inspected:](http://jsfiddle.net/KbMnV/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var $introbrowserwidth= $(window).width();

        $soeg = $('a.soege-knap');
        $mobnav = $('a.mob-nav');
        $soegelist = $('div#search-table') ;
        $searchtable = $('#search-table') ;
        $soegefelt = $('ul.menu-item-holder > #searchfield');
        $menuknap = $('li a.menu-knap');
        $menu = $('div.menu')
        $menulist = $('.menu li')
        $emneoversigt = $('#emneoversigt')
        $emneoversigtlistitem = $('#emneoversigt li')
        $('.mob-nav').css('cursor','pointer');
        $temamenu = $('#tema-menu');


        if ($introbrowserwidth <=480) {
        $soegelist.addClass('displaynone');
        $soegefelt.addClass('displaynone');
        $('#menudiv').removeClass('displayblock').addClass('displaynone');
        $('#menudiv > ul').addClass('background-colour7 zebra');
        $('#menudiv a').addClass('displayblock');

        }       
        else{
                $menulist.removeClass('listitem').addClass('inlineblock');
                $menu.removeClass('displaynone').addClass('displayblock');
                $soegefelt.removeClass('displaynone').addClass('inlineblock');

            };

                $soeg.on("click",function(e) { 

                                            e.preventDefault();

                                            $soegelist.toggleClass('displayblock');
                                            $soegefelt.toggleClass('displayblock');
                                            $emneoversigt.removeClass().addClass('displaynone');
                                            $soeg.toggleClass('soege-knap-aktiv');
                                            $('#menudiv').removeClass('displayblock').addClass('displaynone');
                                            $('#menudiv > ul').removeClass('background-colour7 zebra');

                                            $menuknap.removeClass('menu-knap-aktiv');

                                            $('ul.menu-item-holder').toggleClass('expandheight');

                                            });


                    $menuknap.on("click",function(e) { 

                                            e.preventDefault();

                                            var $menutilstand =  $(window).width();

                                            $menulist.addClass('padding5');
                                            $menuknap.toggleClass('menu-knap-aktiv');
                                            $soeg.removeClass('soege-knap-aktiv');
                                            $soegelist.removeClass().addClass('displaynone');
                                            $('ul.menu-item-holder').removeClass('height expandheight')
                                            $('#menudiv > ul').addClass('background-colour7 zebra');


                                            if($soeg.hasClass('soege-knap-aktiv')) { 
                                            $soeg.removeClass('soege-knap-aktiv');
                                                $('ul.menu-item-holder').removeClass('height expandheight');

                                                };

                                                if ( ($menutilstand <=480) && ($('#menudiv').hasClass('displaynone')) ) {
                                                $('#menudiv').removeClass('displaynone').addClass('displayblock');
                                                $($menulist).removeClass('displayblock').addClass('padding5 listitem');
                                                $soegefelt.removeClass('displayblock');


                                                } else {    $('#menudiv').removeClass('displayblock').addClass('displaynone');}

                                            if ($('ul#menu-item-holder').hasClass('expandheight')){
                                                    $('ul#menu-item-holder').removeClass('expandheight').addClass('height')
                                                        }


                                            });



                                $('#indexbtn').on("click",function(e) { 
                                $('#emneoversigt').toggleClass('displayblock');
                            e.preventDefault(); })




$( window ).resize(function()
                                            {

                                    var browserwidth= $(window).width();

                                    $emneoversigt.removeClass('listitem').addClass('displaynone');
                                    $('.menu').removeClass('padding5');
                                    $emneoversigt.removeClass('displayblock').addClass('displaynone');
                                    $menuknap.removeClass('menu-knap-aktiv');
                                    $('*').removeClass('height expandheight')
                                    $('#menudiv > ul').removeClass('background-colour7 zebra');
                                    $soeg.removeClass('soege-knap-aktiv');


                                            if(browserwidth <= 480 ) {

                                                                $soegefelt.addClass('displaynone');
$temamenu.addClass('displaynone');
$soegelist.removeClass('inlineblock displayblock').addClass('displaynone');
                                                                $menu.addClass('displaynone');
                                                                $menulist.removeClass('inlineblock').addClass('listitem');
                                                                $('ul.menu-item-holder').removeClass('height');
                                                                    $menulist.removeClass('listitem displayblock').addClass('displaynone');
                                                                $('#menudiv').removeClass('displayblock');

                                            $('ul#menu-item-holder').addClass('height');


                                             }
                                            else {      $('li#searchfield').removeClass().addClass('inlineblock');
                                                                $soegelist.removeClass('displaynone').addClass('inlineblock');
                                                                $menu.addClass('displayblock');                                             $temamenu.removeClass('displaynone');                                                           $menulist.removeClass('listitem stroke displayblock ').addClass('padding5 inlineblock');
$('ul.menu-item-holder').addClass('height');
                                                        }
                                        })

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the div with your search:

```
<div id="search-table">
            <span>
                <form id="soege_form" action="<?=$grundsti;?>sider/soegning.php" method="post">
                    <input name="portal_id" type="hidden" value="<?=$valgt_portal_id;?>" />
                    <input placeholder="Søg i alle artikler"  name="soegeterm" border="none" id="soegeterm" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" class="loginfelter venstrefloat boxshadow"  />
                    <button id="submit"  style="cursor: pointer;" class="sendknap venstrefloat button_bg">Søg</button>
                </form>
            </span>
        </div>
```

This is where you assign the div to the variable:

```
$soegelist = $('div#search-table') ;
```

This line makes it dissapear:

```
    if ($introbrowserwidth <=480) {
            $soegelist.addClass('displaynone');
...
```

Comment: Yes, thats makes it disappear until you click the search icon and it reappears. But how come it disappears when you start typing the keyboard on the iPhone?

Comment: Tried to to do this:
$soegefelt.keypress(function() {            $soegefelt.removeClass('displaynone').addClass('displayblock');
 });

And it does add the class, but on the iPhone it still toggles the search input upon typing.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that when typing in the input it affected the width of the document and thus activating my js-resize functions.

Strange thing that it only did so on iOS though.

The solution was to add an `!$('input:focus').length` to the conditions, meaning as long as someone is using any form input the conditions for toggling are not met.

Problem now though is: how to distinguish between wanted and unwanted doc resizing?